# How to overlay a popup on the incoming call screen without losing focus of the current call

Tags: android

I know this is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699257/popup-over-incoming-call-screen) question but my needs are completely different.

I am reading the PHONE_STATE to see if is ringing or not. But the issue is I do that in a broadcast receiver defined in my android manifest. Now when I receive a call I invoke a dialog themed activity since there is no other way that I know of of adding a view to the android phone from my broadcast receiver. But the issue is even if I set the NON_TOUCHABLE flags and several other the incoming call screen still loses focus. I know that I can popup an overlay without losing focus as there are several apps that do just this.

Does anyone know how to achieve this ?

Comment: Nope. A toast does not suit my needs at all

Comment: are you sure ? there are many thing you can do with a toast.

Comment: I guess toast is the only way out.