# How to open app running in background programmatically

Tags: java, android

I have an App where a background service running . When a phone call is detected I want that app to open and show me a particular Intent. How should I do this.

My code is

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void startService(View view){
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                String number = incomingNumber;
                Log.d("gaandu", number);
                if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "incoming call from" + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Phone is currently in a call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Phone is neither Ringing nor in a Call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
    public void stopService(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
        stopService(i);
    }
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return START_STICKY;

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admin.abab">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".MyService"
            android:exported="false"
            />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

In MainActivity.java, after a phone call has been detected, I want to launch my app running in background to open to its first Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the Android [cookbook](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1109):

> You want to act on an incoming phone call and do something with the incoming number.
>
> Solution:
>
> This can be achieved by implementing a Broadcast receiver and listening for a TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED action.

You probably need to do some more research; depending the version of Android you are targeting!

Comment: I already have an action when a phone number is called. What I need is a function that will enable me to launch my app after it has been destroyed or paused, during a call

Answer (score 0):

Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699257/popup-over-incoming-call-screen?noredirect=1&lq=1). hope this will help you. Transparent your activity will help you some what.

[Go through this link also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683952/pop-up-window-over-android-native-incoming-call-screen-like-true-caller-android)

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
```

Comment: I do not want a toast or any window running on top. I want the entire app to be launched.